# Two cookies with Jquery Delay

Tags: jquery, session-cookies

I have a web service im connecting to with jquery using a proxy in between. The first login call returns the jsessionid from the server, the service then sends that through to return the cookie for a load balancer cookie in the second request. How can I delay from the first request to the second so that im passing both cookies in my second page correctly?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just make the second call once the first one is finished?